# adding image to uiimageView image-name returned from sqlite in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uiimageview

I am trying to add a image to UIImageView:

```
UIView *viewTemp=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2, 140, 140)];
UIImageView *tempImg1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 70, 70)];

NSString *imageNameTemp=[[imageNamesArry objectAtIndex:0 ] objectAtIndex:3 ];
tempImg1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:imageNameTemp];
[viewTemp addSubview:tempImg1];
```

When I am executing the code the image is not displaying.
Here imageNamesArry is array of arrays that contains image name at index 3 returned from sqlite query as

```
    while (sqlite3_step(compiledstatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
            {
                char *temp =(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledstatement, i);
                if (temp==NULL)
                    resultStr=@"";
                else
                    resultStr=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp];

                [tempFCardssAry addObject:resultStr];

            }
            [imageNamesArry addObject:tempFCardssAry];
            fcSetsDataAry=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
```

Here "resultStr" is column value and adding to array objects.

If i tried imageNameTemp as

```
NSString *imageNameTemp=@"imageName.jpg";
```

Then the image is added properly.

Comment: You're reallocating imageNamesArry at the end of the loop, and it seems that you're not putting any object in it. Maybe you should change NSString* imageNameTemp = [[fcSetsDataAry objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:3]; like this.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I changed question now. Before adding image i have all objects in array. May be the problem is string returned by array is in correct format. If a used another name manually then it added properly

Comment: What's the value of `imageNameTemp` ? try to NSLog it.

Comment: Also try NSLogging when temp == NULL, whether every string is returning nil or not. Then we can look for the error (if there is) in SQL statement.

Comment: NSLog the imageNamesArry. Is it display the image name properly that is stored in the sqlite ? The images you want to display is in main bundle or document directory ?

Comment: In Logging it returning image names correctly. I added a images filder to xcode.In that folder all my images are present.When i am trying to give same image name as NSString=@"apple.jpg" the image added properly. I am getting problem when taking image name from array which is returned from sqlite..

Comment: Thanks to all. I found my error. Now it is working fine.